# Visual Studio Attach to Process

Tags: visual-studio, hook

How is this tool used? Not the debugger, I mean Tools > Attach to Process.

Does this mean I have the ability to dynamically link a DLL into another application or am I thinking far beyond this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same as Debug > Attach to Process. It gives you the ability to debug a running application.

Comment: The top level Debug menu item doesn't exist until a project is open.  And yes that too is just silly.

Answer (score 0):

It's great for debugging web apps running on your machine. We use it ALOT to debug webparts and SharePoint.